# How can I replace the for loop method with while loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I am new to programming and trying to learn java. I am trying to replace the for loop in this method with while loop. Can anyone help me how I do it as my code I have written is incorrect.

This is original

```
public static int doSomething(int [] a, int x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        if (a[i]<=x) return i;

    return -1;
}
```

This is what I have written so far but I keep getting  i++; is unreachable. Not sure if what I have written so far is correct but I would appreciate any help. Thanks

```
i=0;

while (i < a.length){
    if(a[i] <= x) { 
        return i;
        i++; 
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

return i;
```

Comment: `i++` is unreachable because you have put it below a `return` statement in the same scope.

Answer (score 4):

Only this part: `if (a[i]<=x) return i;` is within `for` loop. Here would be the equivalent:

```
int i=0
while (i < a.length) {
    if (a[i]<=x) return i; // check for condition and return on true
    i++; // increase the counter on every loop
}
return -1; // default return value
```

Answer (score 2):

use brackets after `if` and `while`. its good practice.

```
public static int doSomething(int [] a, int x) {
    i=0;
    while (i < a.length){
        if(a[i] <=x){ 
           return i; 
        }
        i++;    
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything after  return  statement is dead code.

```
i=0;

while (i < a.length){
    if(a[i] <= x) { 
        return i;
        i++; // This is your mistake
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

return i;
```

should be :

```
i=0;
while (i < a.length){
    if(a[i] <= x) { 
        return i;
    }
    i++;
}
return -1;
```

Note that you did an other logic mistake :
In your last

return i;

if a.length==0 the code inside your while loop will not be executed so your function will return 0 however it's supposed to return -1 ;

Answer (score 0):

your i++ is unreachable since it's behind a return statement. You probably want to move it out of the if case.

```
i=0;

while (i < a.length){
    if(a[i] <=x){ 
        return i;
        i++;  //from here 
        }
        i++   //to here
        /* this block is also not what you want, this block would be exectued every time
           a[i] <=x would be false, so probably most of the time. 
        else{
        return -1;     //you should move this frome here
        }
        */
    }

    return i;   //to here, and remove the return i; . If the while loop is done and hasen't returned 
                //with your first return statement, then it shouldn't return with i here either. 
                //It should return with the -1 from above
}
```

Comment: You're mixing good and wrong code. Also this example won't even compile (missing semicolon). I suggest keeping the formatting readable.